# Read text file over internet on python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Here's a text file on the internet (http) http://hughchalmers.com/example.txt. How would I print that in Python 2?

People are saying this is a duplicate, I would like to say that it is not a duplicate, any other script I found gave Error 412.

Comment: Modules like `urllib` or `requests` could help.

Comment: I can't seem to find out how any of them work in terms of this. I don't really do Python much, I'm more of a web developer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, given a URL to a text file, what is the simplest way to read the contents of the text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393324/in-python-given-a-url-to-a-text-file-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-read-the-cont)

Comment: Not a good duplicate.  This server will respond 412 without certain headers.

Comment: +wim Yep, that was the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
>>> url = 'http://hughchalmers.com/example.txt'
>>> urlopen(Request(url=url, headers={'User-Agent': "hey, it's wim"})).read()
'Exmaple Text'
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Will accept as answer in 3m

Comment: Interesting user agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). Their first example shows how:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://hughchalmers.com/example.txt', headers={'user-agent': 'hugh'})
r.text
```

Comment: I've added the user-agent header, so this should work with your server now.