# How to fetch n text files from online and save it to a single text file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, python

Hi I have few files in a domain, 
say

```
example.com/text1.txt
example.com/text2.txt 
example.com/text3.txt
example.com/text50.txt
```

upto 50 links

I'm looking for an script to read all this links and save it's content into a local disk or into a single text file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Server side or client side?

Comment: @YasharAliabasi I just want those data in my local disk. That is client side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, given a URL to a text file, what is the simplest way to read the contents of the text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393324/in-python-given-a-url-to-a-text-file-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-read-the-cont)

Comment: Hi @TLOwater, Thanks for this python tip, I have managed to do with that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help, Finally I found the solution using Python. Below is the script

```
import urllib2  # the lib that handles the url stuff
    for num in range(100001,150000):
        url = "example.com/%s.txt" % (num)
        data = urllib2.urlopen(url) # it's a file like object and works just like a file
        file = open("testfile.txt","a")
        for line in data: # files are iterable
            file.write(line)
        file.write("\n")
```

This will save all the text files entry into a single file named testfile.txt