# read text file content with python at zapier

Tags: python-2.7, zapier

I have problems getting the content of a txt-file into a Zapier
object using https://zapier.com/help/code-python/. Here is the code I am
using:

```
with open('file', 'r') as content_file:
content = content_file.read()
```

I'd be glad if you could help me with this. Thanks for that!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Your code as written doesn't work because the first argument for the `open` function is the filepath. There's no file at the path `'file'`, so you'll get an error. You access the input via the `input_data` dictionary.

That being said, the input is a url, not a file. You need to use `urllib` to read that url. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393324/in-python-given-a-url-to-a-text-file-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-read-the-cont).

I've got a working copy of the code like so:

```
import urllib  # the lib that handles the url stuff
result = []

data = urllib.request.urlopen(input_data['file'])
for line in data:            # file lines are iterable
    result.append(line)      # keep each line, or parse, etc.

return {'lines': result}
```

The key takeaway is that you need to return a dictionary from the function, so make sure you somehow squish your file into one.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Answer (score 1):

@xavid, did you test this in Zapier?

It fails miserably beacuse urllib2 doesn't exist in the zapier python environment.

[image: Configuration of Python in Zapier]

[image: Error]