# Read text files from website with Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello I have got problem I want to get all data from the web but this is too huge to save it to variable. I save data making it like this:

```
r = urlopen("http://download.cathdb.info/cath/releases/all-releases/v4_2_0/cath-classification-data/cath-domain-list-v4_2_0.txt")
r = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
r = r.p.get_text()
some operations
```

This was working good until I have to get data from this website:
http://download.cathdb.info/cath/releases/all-releases/v4_2_0/cath-classification-data/cath-domain-description-file-v4_2_0.txt

When I run same code as above on this page my program is stopping at line

```
r = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
```

and this is taking forever, nothing happen. I don't know how to get this whole data not saving it to file to make on this some operations of searching key words and printing them. I can't save this to file I have to get this from website.

I will be very thankful for every help.

Comment: Why are you parsing a "txt" file with an HTML parser?..

Comment: You mean I should use .read() function with encoding on response object? Becouse this is taking forever too.

Comment: Well, you can at least try to download and process the file in chunks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16696317/771848.

Comment: but I am not allowed to download this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, given a URL to a text file, what is the simplest way to read the contents of the text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393324/in-python-given-a-url-to-a-text-file-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-read-the-cont)

Comment: That file is enormous. I'd expect it take a looooooong while.

Comment: Correction: Not a big file, I'd guess it's a sloooow server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code below can do what you want. Like mentioned in a comment by  @alecxe, you don't need to use BeautifulSoup. This problem should be a problem to retrieve content from text files online and is answered in this [Given a URL to a text file, what is the simplest way to read the contents of the text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393324/in-python-given-a-url-to-a-text-file-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-read-the-cont)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

r = urlopen("http://download.cathdb.info/cath/releases/all-releases/v4_2_0/cath-classification-data/cath-domain-list-v4_2_0.txt")
                                 
for line in r:
    do_somthing()
```