# How to unpickle a file that has been hosted in a web URL in python

Tags: python, pickle

The normal way to pickle and unpickle an object is as follows:

**Pickle an object:**

```
import cloudpickle as cp

cp.dump(objects, open("picklefile.pkl", 'wb'))
```

**UnPickle an object:** (load the pickled file):

```
loaded_pickle_object = cp.load(open("picklefile.pkl", 'rb'))
```

Now, what if the pickled object is hosted in a server, for example a google drive: I am not able to unpickle the object if I directly provide the URL of that object in the path. The following is not working:I get an `IOERROR`

**UnPickle an object:** (load the pickled file):

```
loaded_pickle_object = cp.load(open("https://drive.google.com/file/d/pickled_file", 'rb'))
```

Can someone tell me how to load a pickled file into python that is hosted in a web URL?

Comment: Use this link to get an overview: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393324/in-python-given-a-url-to-a-text-file-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-read-the-cont

Comment: BTW it is not the normal way to use `open()` this way as it is impossible to close the file if you don't assign it to a name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following has worked for me when importing gdrive pickled files into a Python 3 colab:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
loaded_pickle_object = cp.load(urlopen("https://drive.google.com/file/d/pickled_file", 'rb'))
```

Comment: Not working for me: TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str. Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the 'rb' parameter, it is treated as data and triggers a POST.