# importing .txt file online keep giving me an error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This code keep giving me error that it is an invalid argument.
I don't know why it doesn't working

```
path='https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/0636920023784/raw/master/pydata-book-master/ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt'
f=open(path)
f.readline()
```

Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 path='https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/0636920023784/raw/master/pydata-book-master/ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt'
----> 2 f=open(path)
      3 f.readline()

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/0636920023784/raw/master/pydata-book-master/ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, given a URL to a text file, what is the simplest way to read the contents of the text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393324/in-python-given-a-url-to-a-text-file-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-read-the-cont)

Answer (score 1):

That's not the correct way of importing the file. Because the file is being hosted, you'll have to reach the file by making a HTTP Request.

The way to go is by either using [urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/).

```py
import requests

text = requests.get("<your url>").text

# Then it's up to you...
```

Or you can download the file itself and use file handling, but I guess that's impractical.