# How to call Azure Cognitive Services API?

Tags: python, azure, api, azure-cognitive-services

I've created and trained an image classification model using Azure Custom Vision (Cognitive Services) and published the model with API.
Now, I've written a simple code in Python which takes an image from given URL and calls the API. However, I'm still getting this error even though the image surely exists:

> with open(URL, "rb") as image_contents: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]
>   No such file or directory:
>   'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Dalailama1_20121014_4639.jpg'

The code is as below:

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision.prediction import CustomVisionPredictionClient

ENDPOINT = "https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/"
PROJECT_ID = "bbed3f99-4199-4a17-81f2-df83f0659be3"

# Replace with a valid key
prediction_key = "<my prediction key>"
prediction_resource_id = "/subscriptions/97c4e143-9c0c-4f1e-b880-15492e327dd1/resourceGroups/WestEurope/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/HappyAI"
publish_iteration_name = "Iteration5"

# Classify image
URL = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Dalailama1_20121014_4639.jpg"

# Now there is a trained endpoint that can be used to make a prediction
predictor = CustomVisionPredictionClient(prediction_key, endpoint=ENDPOINT)

with open(URL, "rb") as image_contents:
    results = predictor.classify_image(
        PROJECT_ID, publish_iteration_name, image_contents.read())

    # Display the results.
    for prediction in results.predictions:
        print("\t" + prediction.tag_name +
              ": {0:.2f}%".format(prediction.probability * 100))
```

Help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to give an image to the Cognitive Service. You are mixing both ;)

1) Provide a URL to an image that is accessible over the internet. You do this by sending a JSON to the service:
`{"url":"https://sample.com/myimage.png"}`

2) Upload the image as binary in the POST request.

[image]

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/use-prediction-api#get-the-url-and-prediction-key

Your issue is that you are trying to use `open()` for method 2. However, this does not work with remote files in Python. If you want to do this (instead of method 1), use for example urllib2.urlopen like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1393367/1537195).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried to use urllib.request library but have got this error message: models.CustomVisionErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision.prediction.models.custom_vision_error_py3.CustomVisionErrorException: Bad Request Image Format, Uri: 8b0658caa2d44a578167d5dde8f2c19d