# How to understand what is wrong with my Python loop code

Tags: python, import, sum, extract

I have written this code to extract only digits from a text file and then calculate sum of those values extracted . But I am getting 0 as answer which should 285701 in actual. I don't understand what I am doing wrong even after working on it for long, I am not very experienced in programming just started learning.

```html
import re
fname = open("http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_1501185.txt")
sum = 0
value = list()
for line in fname:
     line = re.findall("[0-9]+", line)
     value = value + line
for x in value:
     sum = sum + int(x)
print(sum)
```

Comment: I have some good and some bad news: the good news: it's working for me, the bad news: it's working for me.

Comment: This code works for me.  Are you sure the `open()` call is correct?  `open()` only works for local filenames, not on web urls.

Comment: You can't open web urls with `open()` look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393324/given-a-url-to-a-text-file-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-read-the-contents-of-the

Comment: you shouldn't redefine the builtin ```sum```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't open web urls with `open()` you need to use `urllib.request.urlopen()`:

```py
import urllib.request
import re
fname = urllib.request.urlopen("http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_1501185.txt")
data = fname.read().decode()
data = data.split('\n')
sum = 0
value = list()
for line in data:
     nums = re.findall("[0-9]+", line)
     value = value + nums
for x in value:
     sum = sum + int(x)
print(sum)
```

Output:

```
285701
```

You need to be careful with your variable names naming your variable `sum` causes that you won't be able to use the builtin function `sum()`

It would be better if your code looks like that:

```py
import urllib.request
import re
fname = urllib.request.urlopen("http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_1501185.txt")
data = fname.read(50000).decode()
data = data.split('\n')
value = list()
for line in data:
     line = re.findall("[0-9]+", line)
     value = value + [int(i) for i in line]
print(sum(value))
```

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen)